# Is it possible to run vstest on a Linux machine via a release pipeline through Azure TFS

Tags: linux, azure, tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am working on a release pipeline that should deploy our project artifacts and run tests over them.
The agent is on a Ubuntu machine.
So far I couldn't find a way to run tests over Ubuntu because as microsoft docs say we should install either the Visual Studio or Visual Studio Test Platform using an installer task on the agent.

The problem is neither of them are available on a linux OS , so I am a bit stuck here wondering if there is a third option that we can use to run our tests on this agent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what type of your project is. If your project is .net core, you can try dotnet core cli task. Dotnet test can cross OS. If your project is .net fx, it cannot run on linux.

Run dotnet test command in [.Net Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops#run-your-tests)

[image]

If you are using deployment group , you can run dotnet test command in a bash task and then use a Publish Test Result task to retrun trx files that Test has generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Fortinatelly our project is in dotnet core and I will give it a try.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that dotnet core task is also not available.for linux . I used a bash task instead.

Comment: I test this task on my side, dotnet core cli task should be available in linux, do you get any errors in log?

Comment: I couldn't find the task in the available tasks list in Azure

Comment: You can find this task as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmhVv.png)

Comment: Well the problem is that when I want to add a task to my deployment group I can not see the Task in the list.It only appears when I am adding a task to my agent job

Comment: Well, I confirmed that there is no dotnet core cli task in the task list of the deployment group. I did not consider the use of deployment group before. I updated the answer. If this answer is helpful , you could consider to accept it as an answer. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: And we also used to a Publish Test Result task to retrun trx files that Test has generated so that we can give back the test result.

Comment: The problem is it won't link the associated test plan if you use dotnet task. If you try to run the test plan using the release pipeline stage, it throws an error that 
Validating Stage: The selected stage does not have the right version or settings of the visual studio test task to run tests.